# How to use android-page-curl project for normal activities? like adding buttons to the page etc?

Tags: android, page-curl

I have used android-page-curl project [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/source/browse/trunk/src/com/mystictreegames/pagecurl/ListExample.java). i want to add buttons and other controls to the activity or the pages.? any idea how can i do this?

Comment: Please visit android developer site.

Comment: @ricintech buddy. i know how to put buttons and controls to an activity. what i m trying is.: one view is created by a class in above project. and that project is drawing that view as bitmap. but i want to add expandable listview to that bitmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do this, u can apply other animations like page flip